# Algorithm for minimizing the number of resources simultaneously open while iterating through a series of tasks

Tags: graphs, approximation, scheduling

I have a problem where I'm iterating through a series of tasks and each task requires that a specific file is loaded into memory. The files are not allowed to be unloaded until all of the tasks that use it are complete.

E.g. say I have 6 tasks. I will represent each task as a Python dictionary where "files" indicates the file that task requires:

```
    >>> tasks = [
    >>>     {'files': [0, 3]},
    >>>     {'files': [0, 3]},
    >>>     {'files': [1, 2]},
    >>>     {'files': [1, 4]},
    >>>     {'files': [2, 5]},
    >>>     {'files': [0, 5]},
    >>> ]
```

Initially, my problem was to determine the earliest point that I could close a file given a fixed sequence in which I complete these tasks. I've been able to solve that. Given these tasks and associated resources I make a directed graph where there is a node for each task, and a node for each file. I draw a directed edge from each task to each file that it depends on. I also draw a directed edge from each task to the next task in the chosen iteration order. For the above example the graph looks like this:

[image]

Thus, we can observe that if a file node is unreachable (i.e. at a particular task node, if there is no path to a particular file), then that file will never be needed again and we can close it. Combined with the easy operation of only opening a file when it is first needed, this algorithm will minimize the number of simultaneously opened files given a fixed iteration order.

I'd like to go beyond this. I'm now wondering: what is the *best* iteration order that minimizes the number of files simultaneously opened? The naive algorithm is to compute the above metric for every permutation of the jobs and choose the one that minimizes it. I could also imagine an integer program where there is an indicator variable for each pair of task nodes, and those variables are constrained such that the path between the task nodes is a Hamiltonian path, and then the optimization objective is as stated (although I don't know immediately how I'd encode all of the details, but I probably could figure it out).

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it? Or at least if there is a more efficient way to approximate it? I expect that this problem is NP-hard, but I also expect that it's a known and well studied problem (or at least very similar to one). Is there an existing name for this problem? Any pointers or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. Do you allow to open a file, then close it, then open it again, then close it?  Are you implicitly requiring that once a file is opened, it must stay opened until last use?  2. I don't understand why you need to solve the problem when the iteration order is fixed.  A simpler solution is: open a file the first time it is used, close it the last time it is used (i.e., at the last task that requires it).

Comment: Possibly related: [job scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_job_scheduling)

Comment: @D.W. The file stays open until it is not longer used. Once it is closed it is finalized and cannot be reopened. You're correct that when the iteration order is fixed your simpler solution works, I was overthinking it. I'm now interested in finding the optimal iteration order. It probably is a scheduling problem variant.